# ARIMA structure

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to find the best model structure using the AIC criteria. I already know that d=1 and D=1 with a seasonal component equal to 12. So:

```
best.order<-c(0,0,0)
best.aic<-Inf
n <- length(x1)
for (i in 0:2) for (j in 0:2)  {
fit <- arima(log(x1), c(i, 1, j),seasonal = list(order = c(i, 1, j), period = 12),method="CSS-ML")
fit.aic <- -2 * fit$loglik + (log(n) + 1) * length(fit$coef) 
if (fit.aic < best.aic) {
best.order <- c(i,1,j)
best.arma <- arima(resid(fit), order=best.order)
best.aic <-fit.aic 
}
}
```

And it gives me this result:

```
best.arima 
Call:
arima(x = resid(fit), order = best.order, seasonal = list(order = best.order, 
period = 12), method = "CSS-ML")

Coefficients:
      ma1     sma1
  -0.9275  -0.8904
s.e.   0.0899   0.4776

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0005297:  log likelihood = 143.67,  aic = -281.34
```

Which is completely different from :

```
auto.arima(log(x1),d=1,D=1)
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
     ar1      ma1
    0.4238  -0.8984
s.e.  0.1202   0.0489

sigma^2 estimated as 0.006367:  log likelihood=84.98
AIC=-163.96   AICc=-163.63   BIC=-156.93
```

Which is the correct result?

Comment: Does your `best.aic` compare with the AIC returned by `arima`?

Comment: What do you mean by that? sorry.

Comment: Well you are computing the AIC by hand whilst `arima()` (or it's `print` method) will be computing if for you. So does the value in `best.aic` that **you** computed match the value reported in the output give when you print `best.arima`. If it doesn't match then you are not computing the AIC correctly and that may be sufficient to account for the differences.

Comment: Ah, sorry, ignore me. I see you mean the coefficient estimates are different too.

Comment: Although, why are you comparing the output of `arima(resid(fit))` with the output of `auto.arima(log(x1))` - those don't look like the same input data to me?